# Can an infinite cardinal number be a sum of two smaller cardinal number?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, infinity

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal number.

**My question** is whether there are $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that both $<\kappa$ but $\lambda+\mu=\kappa$?

If AC holds, then the answer is definitely NO. However, can it become YES when refused AC?

Furthermore, what about some sets which are infinite but not Dedekind-infinite, especially amorphous sets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is certainly possible, if $\kappa$ is not well-orderable. For ordinals the laws of addition and multiplication are true without the axiom of choice because these are well-ordered sets. However for cardinals which are not ordinals this can certainly happen.

As you pointed out infinite Dedekind-finite sets are such example. In particular if $A$ is infinite Dedekind-finite and $B\subsetneqq A$ then $|B|<|A|$ and $|A\setminus B|<|A|$, but $|A|=|A\setminus B|+|B|$. Note, however, that if $A$ is amorphous then $B$ is either finite or $A\setminus B$ is finite. You cannot write an amorphous cardinal as the sum of two *infinite* cardinals.

Monro also proved that there are models of ZF in which **every** set which cannot be well-ordered can be written as the sum of two strictly smaller cardinals. One of these models is such that the real numbers cannot be well-ordered, and can therefore be written as the sum of two strictly smaller cardinals.

This is not provably true for sets which cannot be well-ordered. For example there are models in which every set of real numbers is either countable or have size continuum. In such model the real numbers cannot be written as the sum of two smaller cardinals.

---

Here is a short proof which you might like:

> **Theorem.** The axiom of choice is equivalent to the fact that for every infinite set $A$, if $|A|=|X|+|Y|$ then $|X|=|A|$ or $|Y|=|A|$.

*Proof.* If the axiom of choice holds the implication is trivial. Suppose that the axiom of choice fails, then there exists a set which cannot be well-ordered. Denote such set $A$. Let $\kappa$ be $\aleph(A)=\min\{\alpha\in\mathsf{Ord}\mid \alpha\nleq A\}$. Consider the set $B=A\cup\kappa$, where we can assume that $A\cap\kappa=\varnothing$.

The cardinality of $B$ is clearly $|A|+\kappa$, and therefore $\kappa\leq|B|$ and $|A|\leq|B|$. It follows that both these inequalities have to be strict.

- If $\kappa=|B|$ then $A$ can be well-ordered.
- If $|A|=|B|$ then $\kappa\leq|A|$ which is a contradiction to the choice of $\kappa$.

In particular we have found an infinite set which can be written as the sum of two sets of strictly smaller cardinality. $\square$

Comment: The statement I gave and proved is probably known, but it is a simple example of how cardinal arithmetics are messed up without choice.

Comment: Thank you. That's all right.

Comment: You're welcome, again. Do you intend to ask more AC questions today? :-)

Comment: Yes, one more of cardinal arithmetic，but first let me search it for avoiding duplicate.

Comment: I have another question: Can a Dedkind-infinite set be such an example?

Comment: @Popopo: Of course. It is consistent that $|\mathbb R|$ can be written as the sum of two strictly smaller cardinals. $\mathbb R$ is certainly Dedekind-infinite. More generally, note that the theorem I proved means that this is equivalent to the full axiom of choice. So even if there are no Dedekind-finite sets, but the axiom of choice fails, then there is such an example -- and in such case it would have to be Dedekind-infinite.

Comment: Okay, so to be Dedekind-finite is the sufficient but not necessary condition to have such property.

Comment: @Popopo: Not it's not sufficient either. It is consistent that there is an infinite Dedekind-finite cardinals which cannot be written as the sum of two infinite cardinals. However if a Dedekind-finite set *exists* then there is *some* cardinal which can be written as the sum of two infinite and smaller cardinals.

Comment: But if $\kappa$ is infinite Dedekind-finite cardinal, then when removed 1 element it get smaller, hence $\kappa=\lambda+1$ such that $\lambda<\kappa$.

Comment: I see, you meant they are both infinite.