# $|A\times B|= \text{max}(|A|,|B|)$ for infinite sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am fairly sure, given examples $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{Q},\Bbb{Q}\times \Bbb{Q} $, that this is correct, but do not know how to prove it.

In my cited examples the proof has always used some specific property of $A,B$, leaving me clueless as to the general method of solving this. I am especially interested in the case were $|\Bbb{R}|>A>|\Bbb{Q}|,|B|=|\Bbb{Q}|$, though ideally the answer would be more general.

To be explicit, I'm asking for a proof of the statement in the question title, where $A,B$ are sets with infinite cardinalities.

Comment: $|\Bbb{R}|\gt A \gt |\Bbb{Q}|$ would be contrary to the continuum hypothesis

Comment: This proof appears at least once on this site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I searched for a while and found similar questions that seemed similar but simply cited the result.

Comment: (1) That's usually a good thing to indicate, at least in a comment, when posting the question. (2) I'm fairly sure that I posted at least one proof for this fact, let me search through my 400+ posts in [cardinals] and get back to you.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that tied up all the loose ends in a single answer, so I've posted one. I hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This requires the axiom of choice in all accounts.

First because the axiom of choice is equivalent to the fact that every two cardinals can be compared (otherwise $\max$ has no meaning); and secondly because we use the fact that $|A|^2=|A|$ for infinite sets, which is also equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Now, using these two facts we have that if $|B|\leq|A|$ then:

$$|A|\leq |A\times B|\leq |A\times A|\leq|A|$$

In either case you can't quite prove this "explicitly" without the axiom of choice. Even if you do know that $|A|<|B|$, it might still be the case that $|B|<|A\times B|$.

Related threads:

1. [Godel's pairing function and proving c = c*c for aleph cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608538/godels-pairing-function-and-proving-c-cc-for-aleph-cardinals)
2. [For all infinite cardinals $\kappa, \ (\kappa \times \kappa, <_{cw}) \cong (\kappa, \in).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592506/for-all-infinite-cardinals-kappa-kappa-times-kappa-cw-cong-kap/)
3. [Can an infinite cardinal number be a sum of two smaller cardinal number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234107/can-an-infinite-cardinal-number-be-a-sum-of-two-smaller-cardinal-number) (This might talk about sums, but the same argument shows that defining multiplication by taking the maximal of the two implies choice.)
4. [For any two sets $A,B$ , $|A|\leq|B|$ or $|B|\leq|A|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268942/for-any-two-sets-a-b-a-leqb-or-b-leqa)
5. [To be added... maybe?]

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the biggest of the two
$$
|A|\le|A\times B|\le|A^2|
$$

The last piece you miss is $|A|=|A^2|$, that is equivalent to Choice Axiom, and can be proved, for example, through  Zorn's Lemma

Comment: How would you apply Zorn here? The obvious partial ordering by inclusion doesn't work directly.

Comment: I remember it was a strange set you take for Zorn, but can't  seem to reconscruct now. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$A\times B=\cup \{f:\{0,1\}\to A\cup B:f(0)\in A,f(1)\in B\}$.

Now suppose $|A|>|B|$ :

$|A|=|A\times A|$ and $A\times A=\cup \{f:\{0,1\}\to A:f(0),f(1)\in A\}$.

Find a bijection between $A\times B$ and $A\times A$.

Comment: @Alyosha, oops. right:P typo!